# How can I write a sed, awk or other regex one-liner to concatenate contiguous lines beginning with match?

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have files beginning with values I'd like to match in contiguous groups, then remove the new line characters between them. "Contiguous groups" meaning that we only want to remove newlines between pairs of matching lines. Diffs provide a handy example: Say we wanted to remove new line character between added lines, i.e. all lines beginning with a plus sign `+`.

Adapting an answer to [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489410/how-to-join-a-line-with-a-pattern-with-the-next-line-with-sed) gets close, but only groups pairs, instead of continuing to group all the following match lines:

```
sed '/^+/N;s/\n+/ /' path/to/file.diff
```

(Note that the input and expected output *also* concatenates lines beginning with a space. That was a formatting mistake on my part, and being that very helpful answers have been written to answer the intent expressed in the output, I'm leaving as is so as not to invalidate them.)

Example input:

```
--- some/file/path  2021-02-21 16:33:40.000000000 -0600
+++ another/file/path   2021-02-21 16:33:52.000000000 -0600
@@ -32,7 +32,7 @@
 this
 sentence
-lost
-many
+gained
+several
+other
 words
@@ -91,9 +91,10 @@
 this
 one
-just
-lost
-many
```

Desired output:

```
--- some/file/path  2021-02-21 16:33:40.000000000 -0600
+++ another/file/path   2021-02-21 16:33:52.000000000 -0600
@@ -32,7 +32,7 @@
 this sentence
-lost 
-many
+gained several other
 words
@@ -91,9 +91,10 @@
 this one
-just 
-lost 
-many
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;N;s/^(([+ ]).*)\n\2/\1 /;$!ta;P;D' file
```

Append the following line.

If the first line begins with `+` or   and the second line does with the same character, remove the newline and the repeated character and replace them by a space.

Repeat the process until a match fails.

Print/delete the first line and repeat.

Comment: I got to give you this one -- you nailed the expected output!

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` one-liner which will join adjacent lines beginning with a `+` character:

```
sed -e ':a' -e '$!N;s/^\(+.*\)\n+/\1 /;ta' -e 'P;D' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` solution stretches the notion of a 1-liner a bit, but it isn't too bad by long one liner standards, e.g.

```
awk '
    !found && /^+[^+]/ { printf "%s", $0; found=1; next }
    /^[^+]/  { printf (found?"\n%s\n":"%s\n"), $0; found=0; next }
    found    { printf " %s", substr($0,2); next }
             { print }
' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in the file creatively named `file`, you can select-copy and middle-mouse-paste into an xterm with the file in the current directory and would have:

```
$ awk '
>     !found && /^+[^+]/ { printf "%s", $0; found=1; next }
>     /^[^+]/  { printf (found?"\n%s\n":"%s\n"), $0; found=0; next }
>     found    { printf " %s", substr($0,2); next }
>              { print }
> ' file
--- some/file/path  2021-02-21 16:33:40.000000000 -0600
+++ another/file/path   2021-02-21 16:33:52.000000000 -0600
@@ -32,7 +32,7 @@
this
sentence
-lost
-many
+gained several other
words
@@ -91,9 +91,10 @@
this
one
-just
-lost
-many
```

**Note:** your problem statement discusses just concatenating lines beginning with `'+'`, but your expected output also joins the first two lines after the `diff` position information. it is unclear if you want one, the other or both?

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the note, I mis-formatted the output. :) The discussion was the accurate half—just one type of match. Upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work

```
$ awk '{p=substr($0,1,1); 
        if(p!=pp && pp!="-") printf "\n"; 
        pp=p; 
        printf "%s%s",$0,p=="-"?"\n":""}' file

--- some/file/path  2021-02-21 16:33:40.000000000 -0600
+++ another/file/path   2021-02-21 16:33:52.000000000 -0600
@@ -32,7 +32,7 @@
 this sentence
-lost
-many
+gained+several+other
 words
@@ -91,9 +91,10 @@
 this one
-just
-lost
-many
```